# How to check apk files for common security issues before the deployment?

Tags: android, security, deployment, webview, apk

I would like to check apk files for common security issues before the deployment.

Is there any tool which can scan my file?

For example: I am deploying an apk but Google Play notify me that the apk contains a webview vulnerability. -> I would like to avoid from these situations.

Comment: check this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19694/tools-to-help-test-the-security-of-android-applications

Comment: Thanks but quite outdated and there is no tool for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This github repository provides various list of tools like app vulnerability scanners,static and dynamic analysis and so on.It is continuously updated and should be helpful.

[github link](https://github.com/ashishb/android-security-awesome)